# Music player that resumes where last paused

Tags: media-player

Winamp is going away and I like to listen to podcasts. I have to download them from home as my work has a non-streaming policy (even though we have a subway tunnel of an internet pipe, whatever). I have a very specific need which is really hard to search for. I need a media player that will automatically resume from the last place paused. I've been searching for something for days.

I know you are probably going to vote to close this because it looks like a shopping list thing, but I figured I'd give it a try.

Comment: Yes, this is off-topic. Just a friendly warning - there is such a thing as being banned for too many off-topic questions. I would recommend leaving the "who cares about rules" mentality behind.

Comment: I'm not questioning the shopping cart rule. I understand the reason for it. I'm just saying I get the scarlet SC anytime I ask a question that is a little too open ended. Here I have a problem and I'm asking for a single solution, anything, not the best thing. When I'm on Stack, I ask a question and someone gives me some code or a link. I honestly don't see the difference, but I'll limit all my questions to yes/no from now on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[foobar2000](http://www.foobar2000.org/) does that for me. I can close it and it will resume exactly where I left off.